# wordpress how to add javascript to wp-admin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-admin

I am having a hard time on an easy task but seems like I can not find the answer.

I need to add some `js` code to the `wp-admin` page of a `wordpress` and `woocommerce`.

For this I have the following code on the `functions.php`:

```php
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('chcol01', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/aldisjs/admChangeColorScr.js');
}
    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

and I have this code on `admChangeColorScr.js` located on `plugins/aldisjs`:

```js
function chcol(){
    alert("now what?");
}
```

What I expected is an alert notice on the `wp-admin` page when I relod but it does not happen.

What I am doing wrong??

Comment: Where are u calling the chcol function, I think it does not shows alert because the chcol function is never called. Also, check from network files if the js file is getting loaded in wp-admin page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you've defined the `chcol` function in your javascript file BUT YOU HAVE NEVER CALLED/USED IT!

Second point in your code, when you try to inject your js file to admin (or any other page on wordpress), first check whether you're actually on that page or not. Although, `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook should do the trick for you.

For example, in your case, first check whether you're actually on the admin panel or not then inject/enqueue your js file! It never hurts to double check!!!

```php
function my_enqueue() {
  if(is_admin()){ // if it returns true 
    // Then run wp_enqueue_script() function!
  }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```